# How do you refer to a shadowed top-level variable?

Tags: scope, racket

```
#lang racket

(define (shadowed x)
  'the-normal-result)

(define (f . args)
  (define (shadowed x)
    (cons 'local-extra (top-level-shadowed x)))
  (for/list ([arg args])
    (shadowed arg))) ;I want to be careful that I don't accidentally call the top-level shadowed func here
```

As illustrated above, sometimes I want to shadow a top-level function locally, because I want to call a variant instead, and the variant should call the top-level function.

Experience has shown that giving the local variant a variant name, like `shadow^`, leads to bugs, because I accidentally call the top-level function from the inner scope.

How can I "jump out" of the inner scope, or somehow qualify an identifier to refer to its binding in the top level or in an explicitly specified module?

### Update

I found something that looks promising: [#%top](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/__top.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._~23~25top%29%29). However, when I tried it, this is what I got:

```
> (define (f x) (list 'top x))
> (define (g x)
    (define (f x) (cons 'inner ((#%top . 'f) x)))
    (cons 'here (f x)))
. #%top: not an identifier in: (quote f)
> (define (g x)
    (define (f x) (cons 'inner ((#%top . f) x)))
    (cons 'here (f x)))
?: free identifier found in linklet
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in an explicitly specified module"? Is this top-level variable an import from a module?

Comment: @AlexKnauth I mean I'd be satisfied with either: if I could refer explicitly to `shadowed` from `some-module`, then I'd have the top-level problem solved because I could refer explicitly to that module. (I'd also like to know how to refer explicitly to a variable provided by a specific module regardless, though maybe that should be a separate question.)

Comment: @AlexKnauth Oops, actually the top-level shadowing problem wouldn't be fully solved, because explicitly referring to a module would still only be able to access `provide`d variables, but it would still be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
#lang racket

(define (shadowed x)
  'the-normal-result)

(define (f . args)
  (let ([top-level-shadowed shadowed])
    (define (shadowed x)
      (cons 'local-extra (top-level-shadowed x)))
    (for/list ([arg args])
      (shadowed arg)))) ;I want to be careful that I don't accidentally call the top-level shadowed func here

(f 3 4 5)
```

I admit that this is one of the rare instances where the universal "favor define instead of let" shift makes life a bit harder.

Answer (score 2):

#### Simplest case: if the top-level variable comes from *another* module

If the top-level variable is imported from another module, as in this program:

```
; other-module.rkt
#lang racket
(provide shadowed)
(define (shadowed x)
  'the-normal-result)

; main-module.rkt
#lang racket
(require "other-module.rkt")

(define (f . args)
  (define (shadowed x)
    ; I want to use the shadowed identifier from the other module
    (cons 'local-extra (shadowed-from-other-module x)))
  (for/list ([arg args])
    (shadowed arg)))
```

You can use [`local-require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._local-require))) like this:

```
(define (f . args)
  (define (shadowed x)
    (local-require "other-module.rkt")
    (cons 'local-extra (shadowed x)))
  (for/list ([arg args])
    (shadowed arg)))
```

#### More complex case, using scope-set operations to refer to other scopes

You can create the macros `declare-scope` and `in-scope`, which would be used like this:

```
#lang racket
(declare-scope top)
(define x "outer")
(let ()
  (define x "inner")
  (in-scope top x))
;"outer"
```

This API has the advantage that it still works if you wrap everything in an even larger scope:

```
(declare-scope top)
(define x "outer")

(let ()
  (declare-scope mid)
  (define x "middle")

  (let ()
    (define x "inner")
    (in-scope mid x)))
;"middle"
```

In the context of your code, it would look like this:

```
(declare-scope top)
(define (shadowed x)
  'the-normal-result)

(define (f . args)
  (define (shadowed x)
    (cons 'local-extra ((in-scope top shadowed) x)))
  (for/list ([arg args])
    (shadowed arg)))
```

These macros can be defined using scope-set operations (in particular, [`make-syntax-delta-introducer`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-syntax-delta-introducer%29%29)) like this:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-syntax-parser declare-scope
  [(_ name:id)
   #:with stx this-syntax
   ;; This saves the syntax object at compile-time, so that in-scope
   ;; can reference it later.
   #'(define-syntax name (quote-syntax stx))])

(define-syntax-parser in-scope
  #:track-literals
  [(_ scope exp/def)
   ;; This gets scope-stx, the syntax object that was saved when the
   ;; scope was declared.
   #:declare scope (static syntax? "scope")
   (define scope-stx (syntax-local-introduce (attribute scope.value)))
   ;; This delta introducer has the scopes that are:
   ;;  - in exp/def
   ;;  - but not in scope-stx
   (define delta (make-syntax-delta-introducer #'exp/def scope-stx))
   ;; This removes the scopes that are in delta.
   (delta #'exp/def 'remove)])
```

Comment: What is the purpose of syntax-local-introduce in this code? I've removed it and tried your examples which still work as expected.

Comment: I've learned to sort-of automatically put syntax-local-introduce on things that you would consider "out-of-band communication" between macros. By out-of-band I mean something that isn't directly from the input to the transformer function, like `(attribute scope.value)`, which comes from calling the `syntax-local-value` function. The macro expander adds and removes scopes from "in-band" communications for hygiene, but it can't do the same to out-of-band communications. I'm not sure what the difference is in this particular case though.

Comment: I've figured it out. If you replace `(delta #'exp/def 'remove)` with eg. `(delta #'(let ([x 0]) exp/def) 'remove)` then you get ambiguous binding error without syntax-local-introduce in your last example, and 0 for the first. It is along what you're saying - without that invocation the introduction scope of in-scope macro is not removed by the call to delta, which means the x in let is a viable binding candidate as it has the introduction scope on it.